# Tensorflow Keras : Equivalent implementation of Bidirectional RNN gives different results than using prebuilt Bidirectional Wrapper

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Tensorflow Version = 2.0.0

```
num_units = 128

inp = Input(shape = (50,36))

fw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(inp)
bw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(K.reverse(inp, axes=0))

out = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([fw, bw])

brnn_model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Masking(input_shape=(50,36)))
model.add(brnn_model)
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=14, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

With above code I get the same results as with not using Bidirectional RNN and just using a LSTM layer instead. In short the above code fails to act as `Bidirectional` rather it is giving same result as with a unidirectional LSTM layers.

If i use the pre-built `Bidirectional Wrapper` **I get the expected result.**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Masking(input_shape=(50,36)))
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)))model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=14, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I have already checked that replacing

```
bw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(K.reverse(inp, axes=0))
```

with

```
bw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(inp)
```

has absolutely no effect on the results.

I don't understand how is this even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reversing inputs on batch dimension. And yes, that won't have the effect you desire. Instead of,

```
K.reverse(inp, axes=0)
```

Try

```
K.reverse(inp, axes=1)
```

Because the input to the LSTM is a 3D tensor where each dimension represents `[batch, time, input]`. So the time dimension (that is, reversing the input sequence) should be done on `axis=1`.

Comment: This was one of the major mistakes I was making, i have posted the complete solution as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Change `axes=0` to `axes=1` as pointed out by *thushv89*.
2. Concatenate reverse of `bw` to `fw` because the bw layer will contain weights for last time step at index 0. (This will correct `go_backwards=True` case as well

Corrected code:

```
fw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(inp)
bw = layers.LSTM(num_units, return_sequences=True, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(K.reverse(inp, axes=1))

out = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([fw, K.reverse(bw, axes=1)])
```